# nvd3 not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, json, nvd3.js

I am having some issues with getting nvd3.js to display the a proper graph using json.

Currently, the html page shows nothing. I am not seeing any error in the console.

Any help is appreciated.

my js:

```
d3.json('http://localhost:8888/admin/reports/widget_hits', function(data) {
  (function() {
    nv.addGraph(function() {
      var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .staggerLabels(true)
      .tooltips(false)
      .showValues(true)

      d3.select('#widget-hits svg')
      .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart)
      ;

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
      return chart;
    })
  })
  console.log(data);

});
```

my json response output as json:

```
[
    {
        "key": 11,
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "9",
                "label": "2018-01-21"
            },
            {
                "value": "2",
                "label": "2018-01-22"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

my html:

```
<div class="widget-chart" id="widget-hits">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: These nvd3's are hard to nail down due to changing versions and poor documentation. I'm not sure the answer. But a question to followup, does `console.log(data)` show anything? Also on that, little trick, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));` for better visibility.

Comment: Console.log(data) shows the correct json response. I’ll try stringify to see if that works

Comment: Well if that shows what you expect, no need. Is it possible you are running the JavaScript before the html DOM elements are created? I'd say unlikely as the js is async call `d3.json`...

Comment: As I mentioned before, stability/functionality between versions of both d3 and nvd3 can be a bit dodgy. Give us your versions for the two. I'm no "Mike Bostock" by even a fraction, still might be of help...

Comment: thanks rob. my nvd3 ver. 1.8.6, d3 ver 3.5.17. is there another library that is a good alternative?

Comment: couldn't figure out what was broke, but I was able to modify a discrete bar chart on js fiddle using those versions... hope it helps good luck! http://jsfiddle.net/akavdych/

Comment: whoops. that is the link to the example i found and forked, this is the one using those versions... http://jsfiddle.net/visiblemenace/qxbaxkrr/1/